# Genome-wide association study (GWAS) search engine?

Tags: human-genetics, dna-sequencing, human-genome, gwas

I am not a biologist and came across the term genome-wide association study or 'GWAS' for the first time today.

Now I would like to see if there is a GWAS on the particular condition I am interested in finding out about. Is there a search engine that collates all known GWAS and makes them searchable?

Note: the backup plan is to use Google, but I wonder if there's anything dedicated to this particular task.

Comment: Try this https://www.ebi.ac.uk/gwas/

Comment: When researchers write meta-analyses etc. of such studies, they still use the traditional literature search tools, pubmed etc. So I don't think there is a database that has taken off just for gwas.

Comment: Thanks @Fizz (you're a human encyclopedia). Also, you may be interested in [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/95953/61894) question, which is somewhat related to another question you answered